# Is there a way to change an image of an iteratively created button upon clicking it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter, tkinter-button

The buttons are being created in a larger loop iterating through i then j with the following code:

```
btn[i][j] = Button(lbl_frm, width=24, height=24, image=unchecked_img,
                                       command=lamda:change_btn_img(btn[i][j]),relief=SOLID)

                global state
                state = "unchecked"

                btn[i][j].place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='c')
```

with the function to change the configuration of the button:

```
def change_btn_img(btn):
    global state
    if state == "checked":
        btn.configure(image=unchecked_img)
        state = "unchecked"

    elif state == "unchecked":
        btn.configure(image=checked_img)
        state = "checked"
```

However, this isn't working as if I click any button it only changes the image of btn[i][j] where i and j were values reached in the last iteration of the loop.
The buttons are used to form a grid, and in this case clicking any changes the last element in the last row. Is there any way to make it so that the i and j used when declaring the command upon creation of the button are fixed to that specific button?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210557/changing-image-with-button-click-with-python-tkinter

Comment: common problem with lambda in loop: `command=lamda x=i, y=j:change_btn_img(btn[x][y])`

Answer (score 0):

It is common problem with `lambda` in `loop`.

You have to assing `i`, `j` to arguments in `lambda` (ie. `x`,`y`) and it will copy values from `i`, `j` instead of using references to `i`, `j`

```
 command=lamda x=i, y=j:change_btn_img(btn[x][y])
```

---

**BTW:**

In Python you can create own atributes in class so maybe you should keep `state` in `Button`

```
 btn[i][j].state = "unchecked"
```

and then you don't need `global` and every button has own `state`

---

Or maybe you should create own `Widget` - something like this:

```
class MyButton(tkinter.Button):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwars):
        super().__init__(parent, width=24, height=24, image=unchecked_img, command=self.change, relief=tkitner.SOLID)
        self.state = "unchecked"
        
    def change(self):
        if self.state == "checked":
            self.configure(image=unchecked_img)
            self.state = "unchecked"
        elif self.state == "unchecked":
            self.configure(image=checked_img)
            self.state = "checked"
```

and later you could simply use

```
btn[i][j] = MyButton(lbl_frm)

btn[i][j].place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='c')
```

Comment: Working great now, thanks very much. Thanks for your suggestion I have now implemented a button class.

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.